# How to add java doc for selenium 3.0?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium3

For which jar file i should add java doc location, in previous version used to add for selenium 2.x.x.jar but in the latest version it is missing?

Answer (score 0):

Add Java Doc to client-combined-3.0.0-nodeps.jar file. and JavaDoc like can be found [here](http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/). it worked for me.

[image]

Comment: Have you validated the Path?

Answer (score 0):

My answer was

1. open build path '**libraries**' -> '**selenium api...**' expand and click '**source attachment**'
2. choose '**external location**', just include the jar file like '**selenium-api-3.*.*-beta- 2-sources.jar**'

if you need further clarification just reply me.